# How to print a dictionary based on a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This is list of dictionary.

It is basically a sample data, but there are are more items in the list.
I want to basically get the dictionary using a value of the dictionary.

```
[{'status_id': '153080620724_10157915294545725', 'status_message': 'Beautiful evening in Wisconsin- THANK YOU for your incredible support tonight! Everyone get out on November 8th - and VOTE! LETS MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN! -DJT', 'link_name': 'Timeline Photos', 'status_type': 'photo', 'status_link': 'https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/photos/a.488852220724.393301.153080620724/10157915294545725/?type=3', 'status_published': '10/17/2016 20:56:51', 'num_reactions': '6813', 'num_comments': '543', 'num_shares': '359', 'num_likes': '6178', 'num_loves': '572', 'num_wows': '39', 'num_hahas': '17', 'num_sads': '0', 'num_angrys': '7'}
{'status_id': '153080620724_10157914483265725', 'status_message': "The State Department's quid pro quo scheme proves how CORRUPT our system is. Attempting to protect Crooked Hillary, NOT our American service members or national security information, is absolutely DISGRACEFUL. The American people deserve so much better. On November 8th, we will END this RIGGED system once and for all!", 'link_name': '', 'status_type': 'video', 'status_link': 'https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/videos/10157914483265725/', 'status_published': '10/17/2016 18:00:41', 'num_reactions': '33768', 'num_comments': '3644', 'num_shares': '17653', 'num_likes': '26649', 'num_loves': '487', 'num_wows': '1155', 'num_hahas': '75', 'num_sads': '191', 'num_angrys': '5211'}
{'status_id': '153080620724_10157913199155725', 'status_message': "Crooked Hillary's State Department colluded with the FBI and the DOJ in a DISGRACEFUL quid pro quo exchange where her staff promised FBI agents more overseas positions if the FBI would alter emails that were classified. This is COLLUSION at its core and Crooked Hillary's super PAC, the media, is doing EVERYTHING they can to cover it up. It's a RIGGED system and we MUST not let her get away with this -- our country deserves better! Vote on Nov. 8 and let's take back the White House FOR the people and BY the people! #AmericaFirst! #RIGGED  http://www.politico.com/story/2016/10/fbi-state-department-clinton-email-229880", 'link_name': '', 'status_type': 'video', 'status_link': 'https://www.facebook.com/DonaldTrump/videos/10157913199155725/', 'status_published': '10/17/2016 15:34:46', 'num_reactions': '85627', 'num_comments': '8810', 'num_shares': '32594', 'num_likes': '73519', 'num_loves': '2943', 'num_wows': '1020', 'num_hahas': '330', 'num_sads': '263', 'num_angrys': '7552'}
{'status_id': '153080620724_10157912962325725', 'status_message': 'JournoCash: Media gives $382,000 to Clinton, $14,000 Trump, 27-1 margin:', 'link_name': 'JournoCash: Media gives $382,000 to Clinton, $14,000 Trump, 27-1 margin', 'status_type': 'link', 'status_link': 'http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/journocash-media-gives-382000-to-clinton-14000-trump-27-1-margin/article/2604736', 'status_published': '10/17/2016 14:17:24', 'num_reactions': '22696', 'num_comments': '3665', 'num_shares': '5082', 'num_likes': '14029', 'num_loves': '122', 'num_wows': '2091', 'num_hahas': '241', 'num_sads': '286', 'num_angrys': '5927'}

]
```

I want the value for the highest number of `'num_likes'` and print the `status_id` for that particular dictionary which has the highest `'num_likes'`. I also want to understand how the method or process to implement this. I basically use the list to obtain the values and then find the maximum, is there any other way to do it?

The output should be just `status_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm declaring your list-of-dictionaries as variable `list_of_objs`.
Since the `num_likes` value is `string-type` using `int(obj['num_likes'])` to convert the `string-to-int` - passing that to `max` method will return what is th `max_likes` .

```
list_of_objs = [{..}, {..}, {..}]

max_likes = max([int(obj['num_likes']) for obj in list_of_objs if 'num_likes' in obj.keys()])
print(max_likes)
max_likes_objs =[obj for obj in list_of_objs if int(obj['num_likes'])==max_likes]


print(max_likes_objs)
```

Last line what I've printed is `list of all the dictionaries that have the max-value of num-likes`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
k=max([i['num_likes'] for i in d])
[i['status_id'] for i in d if i['num_likes']==k][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simpler list as example:

```
l = [
    {'likes': 5, 'id': 1},
    {'likes': 2, 'id': 2},
    {'likes': 7, 'id': 3},
    {'likes': 1, 'id': 4},
]

result = list(filter(lambda item: item['likes'] == max([item['likes'] for item in l]), l))
print(result)
```

this will print `[{'likes': 7, 'id': 3}]`. The problem here is that if you can have more than one "maximum like item". This is why the function return a list. To print all of the IDs you can to:

```
print([item['id'] for item in result])
```

If you are sure that there are no more than one item or, otherwise, you need exactly one (maybe the first) you can do:

```
result = list(filter(lambda item: item['likes'] == max([item['likes'] for item in l]), l))

result = result[0]['id']
print(result)
```

which will print `3` in the example.

Now how to approach this problem: first you need the maximum number of likes:

```
max([item['likes'] for item in l])
```

call it maxLikes. Then you need the to take all the items with this likes value:

```
filter(lambda item: item['likes'] == maxLikes, l)
```

this is a filter applied on the list l (the last argument on the right), with a lambda function that could be read as "all items with 'likes' property equal to the maxLikes number".
Then you transform this in a list with `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring **list_of_status_ids = [{}, {} ...]**

Iterate list_of_status_ids and add in a dict having key as **num_likes** and values as list of **status_id**. 
Then take **max** of **num_likes** and get all **status_id** corresponding to that max num_likes.

```
from collections import defaultdict

status_id_map = defaultdict(list)
[status_id_map[obj['num_likes']].append(obj['status_id']) for obj in list_of_status_ids]
print status_id_map.get(max(status_id_map.keys()))
```